# Analytic continuation of function of two complex variables

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Consider $f(z_1, z_2)$ a function of two complex variables, symmetric in its arguments $z_1$ and $z_2$. Consider the regions:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{R}_1= \{ (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2: Re(z_1)>0, Re(z_2)>0 \}, \\
\mathcal{R}_2= \{ (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2: Re(z_1)<0, Re(z_2)>0 \}, \\
\mathcal{R}_3= \{ (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2: Re(z_1)>0, Re(z_2)<0 \}, \\
\mathcal{R}_4= \{ (z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2: Re(z_1)<0, Re(z_2)<0 \}.\\
\end{eqnarray}

[image]

The analytic structure of $f(z_1, z_2)$ in know in regions $\mathcal{R}_1$, $\mathcal{R}_2$ and $\mathcal{R}_3$, but not in $\mathcal{R}_4$. The goal is to learn about the analytic structure of $f(z_1, z_2)$ in $\mathcal{R}_4$.

In region $\mathcal{R}_1$ $f(z_1, z_2)$ is completely analytic.

In region $\mathcal{R}_2$ $f(z_1, z_2)$ is a meromorphic function. All of its poles in $\mathcal{R}_2$ are of the type $\frac{g(z_2)}{z_1-a_i}$, where $a_i$ is a negative real number that does not depend on $z_2$. Let $P=\{a_i\}$ be the set of poles of $f(z_1, z_2)$ in $\mathcal{R}_2$. $P$ has limit points in $\mathbb{R_-}$, however it is not dense in any finite interval of $\mathbb{R_-}$.

Similarly, the analytic structure of $f(z_1, z_2)$ is known in $\mathcal{R}_3$ and in this case it only has poles in $z_2$.

I would like to show that in region $\mathcal{R}_4$ $f(z_1, z_2)$ does not develop any new singularities apart from the poles at $z_1= a_i$ or $z_2= a_j$, for $a_i, a_j \in P$. See the picture for an illustration.

One idea would be to use Bochner's theorem. However, the fact that $f(z_1, z_2)$ has accumulation of poles prevents us from immediately applying Bochner's theorem. If anyone has any idea on how to attack this problem, I would be much appreciated.